# Oracle - Export query execution time

Tags: sql, oracle, time, logfiles

I'm fairly new to oracle (running Oracle 12 on a Ubuntu server, using the SQL developer from a windows machine to manage it) and I'm trying to measure the execution time for a bulk of different statements/queries.

What is the optimal and/or convenient way to bulk execute a high number of queries and then export the time required for each of them. The results themselves are trivial, I'm interested in recording execution times only.

Thanks in advance

Comment: I see that this question has a logfiles tag.  Are you logging anything now?

Comment: Only using the internal SQL developer interface. I've edited the configfile and added: "IncludeConfFile sqldeveloper-debug.conf
AddVMOption -Dcom.methodr.loglevel=all". This displays some internal processes, but doesn't seem to allow to log durations.

Might be wrong here though

Answer (score 1):

You can use the DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME function where you need.
For example. try something like this:

```
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON

DECLARE
    my_time   PLS_INTEGER;
BEGIN
    my_time := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;

    SELECT ... FROM ...;  -- Query 1

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Elapsed time: ' || TO_CHAR(DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME - my_time) || ' hsecs');

    my_time := DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME;

    SELECT ... FROM ...;  -- Query 2

    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('Elapsed time: ' || TO_CHAR(DBMS_UTILITY.GET_TIME - my_time) || ' hsecs');

    -- ... and so on ...
END;
/
```

etc...

Oherwise, if you use SQL*Plus, you can set:

```
set timing on
```

and you'll see the elapsed times...